# Нужна помощь в сохранении почтовых контактов

Tags: база-данных, email

Здравствуйте. У меня возникла необходимость импортировать свою переписку из Exchange в Microsoft Outlook. Временно нет доступа к Exchange. Для этого хотелось бы сделать сохранение почты (нужно перестраховаться). В дальнейшем будем переходить на другую почту.
Знаю, где лежит файл ost,  и мне надо из него сделать pst. Вопрос, чем лучше сделать конвертацию из ost в pst?

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте. Для сохранения данных Outlook на компьютере используются файлы данных: «*файлы автономных папок*» (OST) или «*автономными файлами данных* Outlook» (OST) в зависимости от версии. Так же есть *локальные файлы* (PST).

- К сожалению, без доступа к почтовому клиенту Exchange, вы не сможете
  воспользоваться родным средством импорта\экспорта почты. Придется
  работать с тем, что есть, а есть у вас файл формата OST.
- Сам посебе автономный файл и есть сохранённые данных, но если почтой
  Microsoft Exchange, еще пользуются, то вы можете потерять свои
  настройки из-за того, что он меняется при работе с почтой.
- Так как вы знаете, где находиться данный файл, но испытываете трудности в
  сохранении почты. Советую конвертацию в не меняющийся локальный файл
  PST. В вашем случае вы вынужденны ждать пока получите доступ к почте,
  или же воспользоваться сторонним программным обеспечением. Могу
  порекомендовать конвертировать OST в PST онлайн
  https://www.osttopst.online/ru/, а так-же советую
  https://support.office.com/ru-RU/Outlook